# Redux action payload being ignored when dispatching some other action inside axios interceptor

Tags: redux, axios, interceptor

I need to call `checkConnection` before any other action so I thought of using axios interceptors:

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(
  async config => {
    await store.dispatch(checkConnection())

    const { requestTime, hash } = intro(store.getState())

    return {
      ...config,
      headers: {
        'Request-Time': requestTime,
        'Api-Hash-Key': hash
      }
    }
  }
)
```

`intro` is a reselect selector used to do some 'heavy' computing on `serverTime` (serverTime is the result of checkConnection)

`checkConnection` is a redux thunk action:

```
export const checkConnection = () => async (dispatch, _, {
  Intro
}) => {
  dispatch(introConnectionPending())

  try {
    const { data: { serverTime } } = await Intro.checkConnection()

    dispatch(introConnectionSuccess(serverTime))
  } catch ({ message }) {
    dispatch(introConnectionFailure(message))
  }
}
```

So, now every time I dispatch an action that calls for an API the `checkConnection` runs first.

The problem is when the reducer responsible for type that main action dispatched (not the checkConnection) gets called it doesn't even see the payload.

Here is an example of a action:

```
export const getData = () => async (dispatch, getState, {
  API
}) => {
  dispatch(dataPending())

  const credentials = getUsernamePasswordCombo(getState())

  try {
    const { data } = await API.login(credentials)

    dispatch(dataSuccess(data))
  } catch ({ message }) {
    dispatch(dataFailure())
  }
}
```

and its reducer:

```
export default typeToReducer({
  [SET_DATA]: {
    PENDING: state => ({
      ...state,
      isPending: true
    })
  },
  SUCCESS: (state, { payload: { data } }) => ({
    ...state,
    isPending: false,
    ...data
  }),
  FAILURE: state => ({
    ...state,
    isPending: false,
    isError: true
  })
}, initialValue)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reducer is totally wrong. It should be:

```
export default typeToReducer({
  [SET_DATA]: {
    PENDING: state => ({
      ...state,
      isPending: true
    }),
    SUCCESS: (state, { payload: { data } }) => ({
      ...state,
      isPending: false,
      ...data
    }),
    FAILURE: state => ({
      ...state,
      isPending: false,
      isError: true
    })
  }
}, initialValue)
```

Note the SUCCESS and FAILURE parts are now inside [SET_DATA]